# JavaScript table rows - Remove, sort via array, place back in at correct positions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic web application for my workplace, where a PHP script retrieves thousands of rows from an sql database, and places the data in a JavaScript object for me to control on the front end.

I've managed to make all of the above, no problem.

There are a few thousand rows in the HTML table (containing the results).

The JavaScript script dynamically changes the class of the individual s, depending on what 'column' they're in.

I can retrieve all of the 's with a particular class name, no problem, and then store the innerHTML of each of the s within an array, and sort it but how can I then remove the rows they're in from the table, sort the rows relative to the s innerHTML, then place the rows back in the table?

Again, I know how to retrieve the relevant s data, sort the data whilst also sorting where the rows should be placed (using another array) - But **how can I use this array**, that holds the rows 'NEW' positions, and actually apply it to the table?

I want to make this all using just JavaScript - I'd rather not use JQuery. If you remove an element from its parent element - will the child element that was removed actually destroy, or could I remove all rows from the table, sort them, then just place them back in ?

Comment: You should post the answer in an answer, not in the question, please. Then move your question from answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question! I just wasn't brave enough to attempt it.

ANSWERED BY MYSELF.

Here's the function I made:

Where **table** points towards the table element, **className** is the class of the td you wish to sort the rows by, and **ascending** is a boolean variable (true / false):

```
function sortRows(className,ascending)
{
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var elements = [];
    // PLACE ROW ELEMENTS IN AN ARRAY, AS .getElements RETURNED ARRAYS CAN'T BE SORTED
    for(r=2;r<rows.length;r+=1){elements.push(rows[r]);}

    elements.sort(function(a,b){
                                    // SORT FUNCTION
    var x = a.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML;  // VALUE IN 'NAME' <td> OF ROW A
    var y = b.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML;  // VALUE IN 'NAME' <td> OF ROW B
    var c = a.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];         // VALUE IN className <td> OF ROW A
    var d = b.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];         // VALUE IN className <td> OF ROW B
    if(c){e = c.innerHTML;}                                 // MAKE SURE VALUE EXISTS IN DYNAMIC className CLASSED <td> A           
    if(d){f = d.innerHTML;}                                 // MAKE SURE VALUE EXISTS IN DYNAMIC className CLASSED <td> B           

    if(isNaN(e)+isNaN(f))                                   // CHECK IF EITHER THE FIRST OR SECOND DYNAMIC VALUES ARE TEXT - IF SO, SORT ALPHABETICALLY
    {
        e=e.toLowerCase();
        f=f.toLowerCase();
        if(ascending==1){return(([e,f].sort().reverse()[0] == e)*2-1)}else {return(([e,f].sort()[0] == e)*2-1)};    // IF SO, SORT ALPHABETICALLY ascending OR descending
    }
    else if(e==f)                                           // IF VALUES ARE real VALUES, AND BOTH THE SAME, SORT BY 'NAME' <td> OF ROWS A AND B
    {
        return(([x,y].sort().reverse()[0] == x)*2-1);
    }
    else if(ascending){return e-f;}else{return f-e;}        // ELSE, SORT BY VALUES IN DYNAMICALLY RETRIEVED <td> FOR A AND B
    }
    );

                                    // REMOVE ELEMENTS FROM TABLE
    for(e=0;e<elements.length;e+=1)
    {table.removeChild(table.childNodes[2]);}

                                    // PLACE ELEMENTS BACK IN, ORDERED
    for(r=0;r<elements.length;r+=1)
    {table.appendChild(elements[r]);}
}
```

Comment: It may help performance not to remove the rows, just append them to the end. Since elements can't be in the DOM twice, appending them will automatically remove them from their original location.

Comment: OTOH: I just tried it out: http://jsfiddle.net/d2sp2/ (jQuery is only to generate the rows, removing and re-appending them is pure DOM) and there is no obvious lag. Post your code to a new question (possibly in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Maybe you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It's fine now, it all works brilliantly :) I used .sort() with a sort function to sort the rows firstly by the column the user wishes to sort (ascending or descending) and then if two rows have the same value, the sort function then sorts the 'name' column alphabetically. I will post my code in the original post.

Comment: Some remarks about your code: Tables have a [`rows` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.rows), so it's no need to use `getElementsbyTagName`. `getElementsbyTagName` and `table.rows` return a `HTMLCollection` not an array, that's why it can't be sorted. There is however an easy way to convert a `HTMlCollection` into an array: `var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows);`. It's a bit strange to use `+` instead of the boolean or operator (`||`). Your string comparison seems a bit over engineered. Just use `if (a < b) return -1; else return 1;`